# IConvertibleインタフェイス型のリストと値型リストの変換について

Tags: c#

C#において、値型(int, double...)を利用したリストを処理するメソッドを作るために、IConvertibleインタフェイス(doubleに変換して計算する)を利用したのですが、以下のようなエラーを出力してしまいます。

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' から 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IConvertible>' に変換できません

コードの例は以下の通りです。

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                List<int> iList = new List<int>();
                iList.Add(100);
                iList.Add(200);
                iList.Add(300);
                iList.Add(400);
                iList.Add(500);

            //平均を求める
            double aver = average(iList);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("リストの中身を表示します:");
            for(int i = 0; i < iList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("iList[" + i + "] = " + iList[i]);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine("以上の平均は" + aver + "です");

            //出力表示
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 指定された数値のリストの平均値を求めるメソッドです。
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="list">数値型のリスト</param>
        /// <returns>平均値(倍精度浮動小数)</returns>
        private static double average(List<IConvertible> list)
        {
            double rtn = 0;
            foreach (IConvertible ic in list)
            {
                rtn += ic.ToDouble(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
            }
            rtn /= list.Count;
            return rtn;
        }
    }
}
```

iListの型をList<IConvertible>に変更したところコードは問題なく動きましたが、釈然としません。int型はIConvertibleインタフェイスを実装しているのに何故このようなエラーが出てしまうのでしょうか? どなたかご教示お願いいたします。

初めての質問なので拙い点等ございましょうが、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

確かに値の取得しかしないのであれば、基底型として扱えてもよさそうです。

では以下のコードは正しいでしょうか？

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
strList.Add("hoge");

List<IConvertible> list = strList;
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
list.Add(12); // intもIConvertibleなので・・・あれ？
```

`List<int>` に対して `string` 型の値を追加できる、というのはおかしいですよね。いくらあなたが「値の取得しかしない！」と考えていても、それをコンパイル時に保証することはできないため、こういったキャストは許可されていません。

逆に言えば、コンパイル時にそれが保証できればいいはずです。取得しかできないインターフェイス、例えば `IReadOnlyList<T>`。

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
strList.Add("hoge");

IReadOnlyList<IConvertible> list = strList;
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
// list.Add() は存在しない
```

こういった共変性がC#4.0からサポートされているため、前述の `IReadOnlyList<T>` などで利用することができます。が、

[ジェネリクスの共変性・反変性 (C# によるプログラミング入門)](http://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/sp4_variance.html)

> ちなみに、値型（int とかの組み込み整数型や、struct、enum）には共変性・反変性は使えません。 （IL の実装上の制約。）

ということなので・・・。似たような書き方をするなら、`average` をジェネリックにするのはどうでしょうか。

```
private double average<T>(List<T> list) where T: IConvertible
{
    // 中身は同じ
    // where T: IConvertible と書いているので、IConvertibleのメソッドが呼べる
}
```

なお、`List<T>` をはじめとした様々なコレクションやシーケンスが実装している `IEnumerable<T>` では [`Average()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx) という拡張メソッドが使えます。中身の型によって結果の型もdouble以外だったりしますが、参考までに。

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>();
iList.Add(100);
iList.Add(200);

double aver = iList.Average();
```

Comment: 『いくらあなたが「値の取得しかしない！」と考えていても、それをコンパイル時に保証することはできないため、こういったキャストは許可されていません。』
基本でしたが、完全に忘れていました。
『なお、List<T> をはじめとした様々なコレクションやシーケンスが実装している IEnumerable<T> では Average() という拡張メソッドが使えます。』
そのメソッドの存在は知りませんでした。勉強不足ですね。
ただ、今回は「勉強がてら統計処理の一部を自力で実装してみよう」と考えていた(コード例には載せていないが中央値や標準偏差のメソッドを作った)ので、知っていても使わなかったと思います。
懇切丁寧な説明有難うございました。コードのどこがおかしかったのか合点がつきました。参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: それはよかったです。疑問が解決したことが他の方にも伝わるように、回答の左側にあるグレーのチェックをクリックして、回答の承認を行っていただけないでしょうか？ http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000

Comment: 承認しました。はじめてなものでうっかりしていました。指摘いただき有難うございます。